# Passport - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, bcrypt

I'm making a login module, but whenever I put wrong email and password(is hashed, so i need to transform plaintext to hashed), it still goes through and on my node module, it shows this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
at ServerResponse.header (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.location (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:888:15)
at ServerResponse.redirect (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:926:18)
at allFailed (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:145:20)
at attempt (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:180:28)
at Strategy.strategy.fail (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:297:9)
at verified (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:82:30)
at User.findOne.then.user (/mnt/d/WEB/GITHUBREP/node_final/config/passport.js:13:18)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

and my code for my passport is:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('../models/usrschema')

module.exports = function(passport){
  passport.use(
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email'}, ( email, password, done) =>  {
      User.findOne({email: email})
      .then(user => {
        if(!user){
          return done(null, false, {});
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if(err) throw err;
          if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false);
          }
        });

      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
  );
  //fsdfdsfds
  passport.serializeUser ((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
  });

  passport.deserializeUser ((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user)
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the problem is caused in this particular code?  Also, please NEVER write a line of code `if (err) throw err;` in a plain asynchronous callback.  It does absolutely nothing useful.  It's horrible that nodejs documentation all over the place often shows that as it's never a correct line of code inside a plain asynchronous callback.

Comment: Also, you `.catch()` handler presumably needs to call `done()`.

Comment: Looking closely at this stack trace, it appears that your passport strategy hits a failure code path.  Then, somewhere outside the code you've included, you attempt to do a `res.redirect()`, but at that point, a response has already been sent so it's the `res.redirect()` that triggers the problem as it tries to send a 2nd response.  So, if that's the case, then the problem is not in this code, it's somewhere probably before where you're attempting to call `res.redirect()`.

Comment: Thank you, upon looking at my code, the problem is outside this code.


    successRedirect: res.render('profile', obj),   <-----
    failureRedirect: '/'

Comment: OK, you should probably either post the relevant code so we can all see the error and I can write an answer about it or you can delete the question.  You don't want to just leave it in this state where the question doesn't contain the relevant code and no answer can be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i was busy.. in my loginrouter file,

```
pgroutr.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const emailog = req.body.email;
  var obj = {emaill: emailog}
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    // successRedirect: res.render('profile', obj), <- replace this with
       successRedirect: '/profile', //<----- this
    failureRedirect: '/'
  })(req, res, next);

})
```